# Why French text is not displaying properly?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a webpage that has french chars as Café but on the website, it does not display?

it displays like this, Caf� ( 21 )

I have set utf-8 on the page... The database table is also collated as utf8

Comment: Have you tried utf8_encode and utf8_decode?

Comment: What server-side technology are you using to take the data from the database and put it on your web page?

Comment: What's the content-type header sent by the server? Try getting it to specify utf-8.

Answer (score 3):

you can try with `&eacute;` so the browser would parse it?

[see this table](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: I fixed this using below statements, mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
   mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");